# Plotting multiple plot in one figure through loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to plot normal distribution plot but multiple plots in same figure through loops..For first iteration its fine i.e 3 plots in one figure but in other 3 figures it plot only one.here is the code

```
load iris.dat;
iris;
number_of_features = 4;
classes = iris(:,5);
number_of_classes = length(unique(classes));

for class_number = 1:number_of_classes
likelihood{class_number} = struct;

for feature_number = 1:number_of_features 
    likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number} = fitdist(iris(find(iris(:, 5) == class_number),feature_number),'Normal');
end
end
hold all
for feature_number = 1:number_of_features
for class_number=1:number_of_classes
  ppd=iris(find(iris(:, 5) == class_number),feature_number); 
     y=normpdf(ppd,likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number}.mu,likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number}.sigma);
  figure(feature_number)
  stem(ppd,y)
end
end
```

please if any one can check it and tell whats the problem in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but the code below may be work. I have just changed the place of your command.

```
load iris.dat;
iris;
number_of_features = 4;
classes = iris(:,5);
number_of_classes = length(unique(classes));

for class_number = 1:number_of_classes
likelihood{class_number} = struct;

for feature_number = 1:number_of_features 
    likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number} = fitdist(iris(find(iris(:, 5) == class_number),feature_number),'Normal');
end
end

for feature_number = 1:number_of_features
figure(feature_number)
hold on
for class_number=1:number_of_classes
  ppd=iris(find(iris(:, 5) == class_number),feature_number); 
     y=normpdf(ppd,likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number}.mu,likelihood{class_number}.pd{feature_number}.sigma);
  stem(ppd,y)
end
hold off
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but all plots are of same color..i wrote hold all for the different colors but how to know which color is assigned to which class???

Comment: You are welcome. You can write this " color = ['y', 'm', 'c', 'r']; " before the loop and write " stem(ppd, y, color(feature_number)) " instead of " stem(ppd, y) ".